# Further vs. Farther in Cardinal Directions

Tags: word-usage

I understand that typically in American English, *farther* is used for physical distance while *further* is used for metaphorical distance (i.e. *farther* to the restaurant vs. *further* in the book).

However, which word would you use when using cardinal directions? You need to head *further* north or *farther* north?

Comment: Isn't "farther/further north" physical distance? Although I don't think it's a hard and fast distinction, just a tendency.

Comment: It might depend on whether you are driving farther north or turning further to the north.

Comment: Google Books shows both usages in AmE: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=further+north%2Cfarther+north&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cfurther%20north%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfurther%20north%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFurther%20north%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfurther%20North%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cfarther%20north%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfarther%20north%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFarther%20north%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfarther%20North%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Have you checked the usage note and example sentences found both at further and farther in the Merriam-Webster dictionary?

Comment: Technically it is "head farther north" but if this discussion goes on much further, I will pull out my hair.

Comment: I've seen some say one or the other is exclusive to cardinal directions, some that say it depends, and some that say they are interchangeable. Frankly, I don't know anymore.

Comment: @GranteDante then take that as a cue: it doesn't really matter. Use whichever one you want, since natives themselves are so befuddled and/or nonchalant about the attempt to distinguish between the words and come up with a "correct usage." Usage differs among US dialects. The opening line of the MW Usage note should tell you all. Furthermore, the examples of the MW provide sentences using both words to modify a cardinal direction. Usage differs, and for eons, and any attempt to quash the difference is prescriptive nonsense. If you are worried about what a teacher might say, show her/him MW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either *[farther](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/farther)* or *[further](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/further)* in reference to cardinal directions, so, using your example, both "*farther* North" and "*further* North" are correct in usage and mean the same thing.

Here's what you said:

> "I understand that typically in American English, *farther* is used for
> physical distance while *further* is used for metaphorical distance."

Therein lies your problem. That's not correct.

What would be correct is:

> "...*farther*, by definition, is used for literal distance, while
> *further*, by definition, is used for ***both*** literal distance ***and
> figurative distance***."

Anytime you use *farther*, you can aptly use *further* instead. That's because one definition of *further* is *farther*, meaning *further* can be used for literal distance, just like *farther* can.  **However**, the converse is not true. Since *farther* doesn't expressly include using it for figurative distance among its definitions, *farther* can't be used everywhere *further* is used.

Now, that doesn't mean that *farther* can't ever be used in a metaphor or used figuratively. It's no different than any word and can be. It's just that *farther*'s dictionary definition only includes using it for literal distance— or "physical distance," as you put it. Meanwhile, *further*'s literal definition **does** include using it for figurative distance.

**EXAMPLE:**

A great example of this distinction between *farther* and *further* is found in Ford's ad slogan "Go further!" I laugh out loud every time I hear or see those Ford ads. To anyone accutely aware of the difference between *further* and *farther*, it's blatantly obvious Ford is trying to pull a fast one by not using the obviously more relevant choice *farther* but instead using the more ambiguous choice *further*.

You see, in these ads, Ford is overtly advertising reliability and longevity, clearly conveying through accompanying context and imagery that Ford's vehicles outlast its competitors' vehicles, going more total miles to achieve higher ultimate mileage than its competitors' vehicles. So Ford is conveying and clearly wants customers to infer that Ford vehicles "Go farther!"

*However*, Ford's ad slogan quite conspicuously isn't "Go farther!" It's "Go further!" Why?

It's because *further* has the added definition of figurative distance, so by using *further*, Ford implies *further*'s definition of *farther* but can fall back on *further*'s figurative definition to avoid any civil liability for false advertisement and civil liability for any expressed warranty the ads may create should anyone sue Ford after their Ford didn't do what Ford wants customers to infer and fails to literally go a greater distance than Ford's competitors' vehicles.

Even though Ford bends over backwards in these ads to get customers to infer the meaning *farther* from *further*, using the word *further* instead of *farther* gives Ford the legal wiggle room to defend itself in any lawsuit that it wasn't speaking literally but merely figuratively, that it was, for example, saying the plaintiff would figuratively "go further" in life by driving a Ford, a subjective, opinion-based, legally unactionable measure, not literally go more miles in a Ford vehicle than in a competitor's vehicle, not "Go farther!" Ford could then further underscore that it didn't mean literally more miles by claiming that *further*'s figurative meaning was precisely the reason it chose "further" over "farther" for the ad campaign.

Comment: You perfectly explained it! Thank you for the example about Ford; it was an eye-opener.